# KeyError: "['Row'] not found in axis"

Tags: python

[I have 3 "Unrated" features in my column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWyuG.png)

[I wanted to drop them but it gave this error ;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdRMN.png)

That is the code I used ( Stars is the name of the column )

```
df.Stars.drop("Unrated",axis= 0)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
df[df.Stars!="Unrated"]
```

It will return a new data frame with all the records (rows) of df where Stars is different from "Unrated".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the built in 'drop' functionality:

```
df.drop(df[df.Stars!='Unrated'].index, inplace=True)
```

But this option will work either:

```
df = df[df.Stars!='Unrated']
```